# How to zip blobs using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using latest the azure sdk Azure.Storage.Blobs version 12.9.1 for C# . I have to move all blobs from one container to another . I have listed all blobs but I am stuck at how to open an output stream to write a blob in another container .

```
 FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("\\" + str+"zip");


            using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fs))
            {
                foreach (var blobFileName in files)
                {
                    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(5);
                    var blob = dirFromZip.GetBlobClient(blobFileName);
                    var entry = new ZipEntry(blobFileName);
                    zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    blob.DownloadTo(zipOutputStream);
                }
            fs.Position = 0;
            var blobClient = dirwhereZip.GetBlobClient(str);
            blobClient.Upload(fs);
            zipOutputStream.Finish();
                zipOutputStream.Close();
            }
```

Error : System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.

Comment: How many blobs do you want to zip? If the number and the size of blobs is small you can probably use a MemoryStream otherwise use a FileStream.

Comment: You mean using  FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(); . How do I add blob reference in the OpenWrite(" ") argument.

Comment: You save the zip file to disk and then upload that file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.IO;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

namespace SO68566758
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        private const string sourceContainer = "source-container";
        private const string targetContainer = "target-container";
        private const string outputBlobName = "backup.zip";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainer);
            BlobContainerClient targetContainerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(targetContainer);
            var blobs = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
            using (var fs = new FileStream(outputBlobName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fs))
                {
                    await foreach (var blob in blobs)
                    {
                        var blobName = blob.Name;
                        var blobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
                        //var downloadResponse = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
                        //var streamContent = downloadResponse.Value.Content;
                        var entry = new ZipEntry(blobName);
                        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(zipOutputStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            BlobClient targetBlob = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(outputBlobName);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputBlobName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await targetBlob.UploadAsync(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```